# Accessing multiple GPUs on different hosts using LSF

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing, multi-gpu, lsf

I am using a HPC cluster with LSF Resource manager. The task is to train a tensorflow model. The graphics queue **gq** (Max jobs 96) has two hosts host1 with 4 GPUs and host2 with 3 GPUs. I want to use the total 7 GPUs together.

The below are various combinations of bsub commands and the results:-

1.
 `bsub -q gq -n 96 -gpu "num=7:mode=shared:j_exclusive=no" -W 6:00 -o output2.log -e error2.log "module load cuda; ./file.sh"`

PENDING REASONS: There are no suitable hosts for the job

2.
 `bsub -q gq -n 96 -gpu "num=4:mode=shared:j_exclusive=no" -W 6:00 -o output2.log -e error2.log "module load cuda; ./file.sh"`

PENDING REASONS: Not enough hosts to meet the job's spanning requirement;

3.
 `bsub -q gq -n 96 -gpu "num=3:mode=shared:j_exclusive=no" -W 6:00 -o output2.log -e error2.log "module load cuda; ./file.sh"`

Running. 96 Tasks started on 2 hosts. But only 3 GPUs from Host 1 are used

4.
 `bsub -q gq -gpu "num=4:mode=shared:j_exclusive=no" -W 6:00 -o output2.log -e error2.log "module load cuda; ./file.sh"`

Running. 1 Tasks started on host1. All 4 GPUs from Host 1 are used

**What should I do so that I can use all 7 GPUs and 96 tasks across both the hosts??**

Comment: Its looks like you trying to distribute your TensorFlow training job across multiple GPUs on different hosts using the LSF Resource Manager. The issues you are facing is related to how LSF allocates resources, especially when dealing with GPU resources across multiple hosts. To achieve your goal of using all 7 GPUs and 96 tasks across both hosts, you can try this following approach: 
`Goal: Utilize all 7 GPUs across host1 and host2 for 96 tasks, 
host1: 4 GPUs,
host2: 3 GPUs`